# How to access the width and height inside of this in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to get the width and height of .more class and .popovercontent div using jquery. popover-content class width is dynamic it can be change as i am getting the width from my database. Iam getting the below division by this. so i want to know how to get the width and height using this

```
console.log(this);
```

It display the below result

```
<div id="picture1-more4" class="more more32 ltr-slide bgblack" style="top: 288px; left: 549px; z-index: 1; width: 32px; height: 32px;">
<div class="imgButton imgButtonDrag imgButtonDrag imgButtonDrag imgButtonDrag imgButtonDrag imgButtonDrag imgButtonDrag imgButtonDrag moreblack"></div>
<div class="popover-inner red" style="margin-left:50px;">
<div class="arrow-right3" style="display: inline-block !important; border-left-width: 10px; border-left-style: solid; border-left-color: green; border-top-width: 10px; border-top-style: solid; border-top-color: transparent; border-bottom-width: 10px; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: transparent; position: absolute; top: 50%;"></div>
<h4 class="popover-title"><a href="" target="self">Garden</a></h4>
<div class="popover-content" style="width:400px;"><p>To view details about either the Security or Maintenance section, click the heading or the arrow next to the heading to expand or collapse the section. If you dont want to see certain types of messages, you can choose to hide them from view. </p></div>
</div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the problem is that you need to specify what `$(this)` is.
As you can see in my fiddle i loop through every div, meaning that `$(this)` now is the "div" it is looping through at that moment.

http://jsfiddle.net/4oq27b3r/

but why use `$(this)` if you know the classes you want to get the width from?
As said by others this is way easier:

```
$('.more').width()
$('.popover-content').width()
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Jquery, you can try this

var width = $('.test').width();

var height = $('.test').height();

Comment: I already know that tag but it wont work as i want to get the width and height using "this"

Answer (score 0):

You can use as below

```
$(this).width()
$(this).height()
```

Comment: I want to get the height and width of class more and popover-content

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer